# Labview OPC UA server (Error occured while reading the node)

Tags: labview, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to implement the following example (http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622M-01/lvmve/using_opcua_svr/) but there seems to be in error in my code which i can't figure out. The error is "Error occurred while reading the node". Below is my Block diagram. If a write before read the error become error
in writing the node.

[image]

Comment: I notice that you have a coercion dot at your first "Add Item.vi". Is your cluster correct? Anyway, in LabVIEW, go to Help -> Find Examples... then, search for the "OPCUA" keyword. Open "OPC UA Demo.lvproj" and run it. Does it work?

Comment: yes that was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the write.vi is not wired up properly. The coercion dots should not appear. Try using context help (ctrl+H) and check the wires once again.

Moreover you can use "highlight execution" option to check where the error message come from.